# Wordpress - the_author() empty only on index.php when not logged in

Tags: wordpress

All right, I'm getting really pissed by WordPress. It just doesn't do what it's supposed to do and nobody seems to know why.

Here's the situation:
I have two different ways to load posts. One is in index.php and another one is in loop.php. The first one loads the first 4 posts, the latter loads more posts when scrolling down or clicking on the "load more" button. Both are inside the loop.

The code is THE SAME, but index.php doesn't show anything when I call the_author, when a user is not logged in. When I'm logged in, I see the author name all the time and when logged out, I only see the name on newly loaded posts.

Any ideas ?
The website is test.nowillnoskill.net

Comment: can you give us the code you use to switch from `index.php` to `loop.php`  *tip: change the font, it's unreadable

Comment: I don't switch. I use the loop.php only to load new articles with AJAX. I copied the same code that's in index.php.
What do you unreadable ? Do you have a problem with rendering ? Which browser ?

Comment: In FF en chrome the webfont is very hard to read, it might me acceptable as heading, but as a content text it's hard to read. I would leave and not read anything.